# parent and parentElement not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm running into compatibility issue with IE11. Specifically, `var opensubs = parent.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');` throws an error. I think it's `parent.parentElement` giving the hiccup, but I'm having a hard time finding resources online. Is there an alternative to the code so that it will work in IE?

Below is the full script. It works fine in other browsers execept in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="tree">
    <li class="myCSS"><a class="tablinks">Parent 1</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="myCSS"><a class="tablinks">Parent 2</a>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li class="myCSS"><a class="tablinks">Parent 3 expander</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="myCSS">Child</li>
            <li class="myCSS">Child</li>
            <li class="myCSS">Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        var closeAllOpenSiblings = function(){        
            var opensubs = parent.parentElement.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        }
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
        } else {
            closeAllOpenSiblings();
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}

</script>

<style>
ul.tree li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.tree li ul {
    display: none;
    
}

ul.tree li.open > ul {
    display: block;
}

</style>

</html>
```

Comment: parentElement and querySelectorAll should work in IE 9+, classList should work in 10+. What version of IE are you using? And please post the error text.

Comment: I'm using IE 11. And there is no error message. It's a syntax error, according to debugging mode.

Comment: There's no syntax error in the code you posted. Again, please post the error text. I cannot reproduce.

Comment: ``SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError`` Is what I see. I guess it helps to say that the code is for a menu tree that expands and collapses. It expands/collapses in other browsers except in IE11.

Comment: The syntax error is probably in the css selector.